# gettext implementation without putenv

Tags: php, gettext

I would like to use `gettext()` in my project, but my webhosting does not support the `putenv()` function.  Is there any way to use `gettext()` without `putenv()`?

Example of code:

```
putenv('LANG=' . $language);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

// Set the text domain as 'messages'
$domain = "messages";
bindtextdomain($domain, "Locale");
textdomain($domain);
```

Comment: `putenv()` doesn't need any special support as far as I know. Do you mean that they've explicitly disabled it with e.g. [disable_functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)? Whatever, gettext totally depends on environment and I believe that's the only way to set it. Also, I hope it's some kind of free hosting because that's a pretty basic feature.

Comment: What do you mean "does not support"? Do you get an error message? What is it?

Comment: Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /data/web/virtuals/134860/virtual/www/.....php on line 3

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález gettext does not depend on environment variables at all. The application sets the locale with `setlocale()`, and in a server application you normally hardode the locale value (2nd argument), so that the environment is completely ignored. The gettext runtime just queries the locale via `setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, NULL)`, and it doesn't care how the locale was set.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are only evaluted, when the second argument to `setlocale()` is `NULL` or the empty string, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php.  Your call to `putenv()` should therefore not have any effect, and you can simply omit it.